# Convert String type value to a object type VBS

Tags: string, object, vbscript, type-conversion

I need to pass an object type value to a procedures, which read from a text file (String fromat).

```
'param node- Object type
'param txtvalue - String
Function setTexttoElement(nodename, txtvalue)
    nodename.Text = txtvalue
End Function
```

Method is finely works when passing following values

```
setTexttoElement myElement, abc
```

But when reading a file it's take String format. So I need to convert first value as Object

> "myElement", "abc"

How to solve this?

Comment: What kind of object expects the `nodename` argument? Are we talking about XML/HTML?

Comment: yes..
Set myElement= CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a reference dictionary to convert the text string to an object effectively, as there is no way for vbscript to know what type of object you are passing to the function. For more information: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155682/vbscript-reference-object-by-string-variable).